# type of inheritance in php

Tags: php, oop

which type of inheritance supported in php?

Comment: Are you aware there is a [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single inheritance, including abstract base classes and final methods, and multiple interfaces. Pretty much like Java.

Comment: interface  supports multiple inheritance

Comment: Yes. That's why I wrote 'multiple interfaces'. Strictly speaking, implementing an interface is not inheritance though.

Answer (score 4):

Single Inheritance only. But you can inherit multiple levels deep.

See

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Php/Class/Inheritance.htm